# Wcf REst Service failed to accept the input values from Angular JS Application

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Service into Angular JS application but its not working according my expection. I am trying to send money to one account to another account using Sql transaction method. When i clicked the submit button in angular js application it is unable to post the input values to wcf service.I checked the console window into Google Chrome i did find any error when i clicked the submit button

Here is the local class named Money Transfer...

```
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MoneyTransfer
    {
        string sender_account_no;
        string sender_name;
        string sender_sort_code;
        string amount1;
        string transcation_type;
        string date;
        string receiver_account_no;
        string receiver_name;
        string receiver_sort_code;
        string amount2;
        string transcation_type1;
        string date1;

        [DataMember]
        public string Sender_Account_No
        {
            get { return sender_account_no; }
            set { sender_account_no = value; }


        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Sender_Name
        {
            get { return sender_name; }
            set { sender_name = value; }

        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Sender_Sort_Code
        {
            get { return sender_sort_code; }
            set { sender_sort_code = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Amount
        {
            get { return amount1; }
            set { amount1 = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Transcation_Type
        {
            get { return transcation_type; }
            set { transcation_type = value; }

        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set { date = value; }


        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Receiver_Account_No
        {
            get { return receiver_account_no; }
            set { receiver_account_no = value; }


        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Receiver_Name
        {
            get { return receiver_name; }
            set { receiver_name = value; }

        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Receiver_Sort_Code
        {
            get { return receiver_sort_code; }
            set { receiver_sort_code = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Amount1
        {
            get { return amount2; }
            set { amount2 = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Transcation_Type1
        {
            get { return transcation_type1; }
            set { transcation_type1 = value; }

        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Date1
        {
            get { return date1; }
            set { date1 = value; }


        }

    }
}
```

Here is my interface.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/MoneyTranfer")]
       bool  MoneyTranfer(MoneyTransfer mopneyTransfer);
```

Here is my Implementation.

```
  public bool MoneyTranfer(MoneyTransfer mopneyTransfer)
            {

                int amount = System.Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount);
                int amount1 = System.Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount1);

                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                string sql = "select Account_Balance from Current_Account_Details where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No + "'";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cn.Open();

                //amount = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                if (amount > 0)
                {
                    int b;
                    int b1;
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                    SqlTransaction trans;
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Open();
                    trans = cn.BeginTransaction();

                    cmd1.Connection = cn;
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd1.Transaction = trans;
                    cmd1.CommandText = "update Current_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance-'" + mopneyTransfer.Amount + "' where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No + "'";
                    b = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd1.CommandText = "update Reward_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance+'" + mopneyTransfer.Amount1 + "' where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Account_No + "'";
                    b1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (b == 1 && b1 == 1)
                    {
                        trans.Commit();
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                        {
                            //Create the SqlCommand object
                            //Create the SqlCommand object
                            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Current_Account_WITHDRAR", con);
                            //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                            cmd3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            //Add the input parameters to the command object
                            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No);
                            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Name", mopneyTransfer.Sender_Name);
                            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", mopneyTransfer.Amount);


                            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort_Code", mopneyTransfer.Sender_Sort_Code);
                            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transcation_Type", mopneyTransfer.Transcation_Type);
                            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", mopneyTransfer.Date);

                            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Reward_Account_Dposit", con);
                            //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                            cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            //Add the input parameters to the command object
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Account_No);
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Name", mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Name);
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", mopneyTransfer.Amount1);


                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort_Code", mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Sort_Code);
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transcation_Type", mopneyTransfer.Transcation_Type1);
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", mopneyTransfer.Date1);




                            //Open the connection and execute the query

                            con.Open();
                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            return true;
                            //con.Close();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        trans.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;

            }
```

Here is script code.

```
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  



var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;

        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;

            $scope.Sender_Account_No = "";
            $scope.Sender_Name = "";
            $scope.Sender_Sort_Code = "";
            $scope.Amount = "";
            $scope.Transcation_Type = "";
            $scope.Date = "";

            $scope.Receiver_Account_No = "";
            $scope.Receiver_Name = "";
            $scope.Receiver_Sort_Code = "";
            $scope.Amount1 = "";
            $scope.Transcation_Type1 = "";
            $scope.Date1 = "";

        }
        $scope.transfer = function () {
            var User = {
                Sender_Account_No: $scope.Sender_Account_No,
                Serder_Name: $scope.Serder_Name,
                Sender_Sort_Code: $scope.Sender_Sort_Code,
                Amount: $scope.Amount,
                Transcation_Type: $scope.Transcation_Type,
                Date:$scope.Date ,

                Receiver_Account_No: $scope.Receiver_Account_No ,
                Receiver_Name: $scope.Receiver_Name,
                Receiver_Sort_Code: $scope.Receiver_Sort_Code ,
                Amount1: $scope.Amount1,
                Transcation_Type1: $scope.Transcation_Type1,
                Date1:$scope.Date1 

            };
            if ($scope.OperType === 1) {
                var promisePost = myService.post(User);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.Id = pl.data.Id;
                    $scope.msg = "Operation is successful";


                }, function (err) {
                    $scope.msg = "Operation is failed !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                });
            } else {

            }

        };



    }]);

app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    //Create new record  
    this.post = function (User) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/MoneyTranfer",
            data: JSON.stringify(User)
        });
        return request;

    }

})
```

HERE IS the HTML

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html data-ng-app="WebClientModule">
<head title="ASAS">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/MoneyTransfer.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{msg}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Sender Account No</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sender_account_no" data-ng-model="Sender_Account_No" required="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Serder_Name</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="serder_name" required data-ng-model="Serder_Name" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Sender_Sort_Code</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sender_sort_code" required data-ng-model="Sender_Sort_Code" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Amount_to_Send</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="amount_to_send" required data-ng-model="Amount_to_Send" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Transcation_Type</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="transcation_type" required data-ng-model="Transcation_Type" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Date</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="date" required data-ng-model="Date" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Reciver Account No</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="render_account_no" data-ng-model="Reciver_Account_No" required="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Reciver_Name</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="reciver_name" required data-ng-model="Reciver_Name" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Reciver_Sort_Code</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="reciver_sort_code" required data-ng-model="Reciver_Sort_Code" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Amount_to_Recived</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="amount_to_recive" required data-ng-model="Amount_to_Recive" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Transcation_Type</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="transcation_type1" required data-ng-model="Transcation_Type1" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Date</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="date1" required data-ng-model="Date1" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="Createuser" value="Submit" data-ng-click="transfer()" />
                            <input type="button" id="Clear" value="Clear" data-ng-click="Clear()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

<script src="~/RegistrationScript/MoneyTransfer.js"></script>
```

Here is screen shot on debugging mode ..

[Click here to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsB6h.png)

Here is the screen shot when I run the application..

[click here to see the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umnwt.png)

Any feedback or suggestion would be highley appricited . Thanks

Network tab..[image: click here to see the result]

Comment: `checked the console window into Google Chrome i did find any error when i clicked the submit button` - so ... what is the error in your screenshot?

Comment: `it is unable to post the input values to wcf service` - check the request in the developer tools network tab - what do the "parameters" of the request look like?

Comment: I checked on network tab . Its taking the input values with 200 ok.

Comment: But wcf service unable to receive those values and perform the operations

Comment: did you miss the question? what do the request parameters look like?

Comment: All the parameters in Json format

Comment: right ... I ask because I want to SEE WHAT THE (in Chrome terms) REQUEST PAYLOAD looks like - take a screenshot of the "request payload" and add it to the question please

Comment: Just a minute please

Comment: to be honest, it would be better to post the `unparsed` request payload - rather than a useless image of it

Comment: updated my question

Comment: {Sender_Account_No: "3", Serder_Name: "rasel", Sender_Sort_Code: "11-990-00",…}
Date
:
"11/9/12"
Date1
:
"11/8/12"
Sender_Account_No
:
"3"
Sender_Sort_Code
:
"11-990-00"
Serder_Name
:
"rasel"
Transcation_Type
:
"withdraw"
Transcation_Type1
:
"deposit"

Comment: here it is image and code on comments

Comment: that's not all of it ... click `view source` copy/paste the WHOLE lot

Comment: {"Sender_Account_No":"3","Serder_Name":"rasel","Sender_Sort_Code":"11-990-00","Transcation_Type":"withdraw","Date":"11/9/12","Transcation_Type1":"deposit","Date1":"11/8/12"}

Comment: got it .check it now please

Comment: well ... there's no `Amount` or `Amount1` for a start, is there, or any `Receiver_*` properties either - this is basic debugging, you look to see what the client sends, it's not sending what the server wants ... problem

Comment: {"Sender_Account_No":"3","Serder_Name":"rasel","Sender_Sort_Code":"11-990-00","Transcation_Type":"withdraw","Date":"11/9/12","Transcation_Type1":"deposit","Date1":"11/8/12"}

Comment: yes, you can keep posting the same stuff over and over ... the required fields are missing

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: why? now that's a question, because your code suggests they SHOULD be there

Comment: i have that input filed in html but why it is not receiving values ?????

Comment: unless `$scope.Amount` etc are `undefined` (not empty string, like what `ClearModels` function does) - then `JSON.stringify` will ignore them - can't see where you populate those `$scope` properties

Comment: it is defined in script file

Comment: `JSON.stringify({present:true, absent:undefined})` results in `"{"present":true}"` so ..

Comment: `it is defined in script file` which one where? can't see `$scope.Amount = some value` anywhere

Comment: Amount:$scope.Amount......Amount1:$scope.Amount1

Comment: it's like banging my head against a wall ... **where is `$scope.Amount` defined**

Comment: The value will come from input filed

Comment: how? which field? is it an input field that has some attribute = `Amount` ... how does $scope "know" what `Amount` (etc) are?

Comment: The value will come from input filed...$scope.Amount = some value anywhere

Comment: yesterday you asked about this ... your javascript code used `Amount_to_Send` and `Amount_to_Receive` ... but the server expected `Amount` and `Amount1` ... did you make ALL the necessary changes on the client code changing ALL references to `Amount_to_Send` etc to `Amount` etc?

Comment: you mean i have to change id ..on this   <input type="text" id="Amount" required data-ng-model="Amount_to_Recive" require="" />

Comment: yes i did it but stil same result

Comment: or, simply - **show** your html form source

Comment: `data-ng-model` attribute

Comment: i makes all the changes as you suggest

Comment: i added the HTML as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
<input type="text" id="amount_to_recive" required data-ng-model="Amount_to_Recive" require="" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="amount_to_recive" required data-ng-model="Amount1" require="" />
```

etc ... the `data-ng-model` attribute is the important attribute that maps to `$scope`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: it took two questions over two days and almost 40 comments to get there ... but, we got there :p

Comment: It is able to catch all the values but Wcf Service not  receiveing  those input fileds values and not invocking the method